# Moving the .hg folder

Tags: mercurial

Hey, I'm using Mercurial. I just found out that there is a .hg folder in my home directory. I presume it is keeping track of all mercurial repositories I have lying around in my home directory. Is this true?

Also , I need to move the .hg folder to another directory. Can anyone guide me as to how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain why you want to move .hg elsewhere.

Comment: I am limited by very small quota on my home directory and .hg is taking up 22 mb but I don't have a quota for the volume on which the alternate directory exists.

Comment: So just clone it elsewhere, `hg clone /path/to/repo /volume/without/quota/repo`.

Once it's cloned you can safely delete the .hg (there's a .hg per repo).

But your setup doesn't look right, and I guess you made a mistake and you didn't really want this repo (or this repo layout).

Comment: A `.hg` folder keeps track of *one* repo only.  If you've got one in your home directory it means your home directory is under version control.  Is this what you want?

Comment: No. I did not want my home directory under version control. That's the reason because I was trying to figure out if the .hg was because I had accidentally put my home folder on version control or because it was keeping track of the various hg repositories in my home directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a .hg/ in your home directory indicates that your entire home directory is under version control, which probably is not what you want. Mercurial does not "keep track" of multiple repositories.

To move a repository somewhere else, use "hg clone".

Answer (score 3):

1. no
2. `cp src dst`, or better `hg clone`

In contrast to e.g. `svn`, mercurial keeps all repository related information under one directory, so you just need to move this directory to its destination.

Ps. It's a little unusual to have a repository (`.hg`) under home, though. More typically, you'll find a `.hgrc` under home, which contains [some mercurial configuration](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html).

More on mercurial usage and internals: [http://hgbook.red-bean.com](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/)